# How do I make my if conditions repeat in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

Basically I want to be able to input a number that isn't an option and then be given the option to choice again and get the statement to repeat.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double weight;
    int Choice;

    System.out.println("What is your weight in pounds?");
    weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Which planet would you like to see your weight on?\n 1. Venus   2. Mars 3. Jupiter\n 4. Saturn  5. Uranus   6. Neptune");
    Choice =keyboard.nextInt();

    if (Choice == 1){
        System.out.println("Your weight on Venus would be " + (weight * 0.78));
    }
    else if (Choice == 2){
        System.out.println("Your weight on Mars would be " + (weight * .39));
    }
    else if (Choice == 3){
        System.out.println("Your weight on Jupiter would be " + (weight * 2.65));
    }
    else if (Choice == 4){
        System.out.println("Your weight on Saturn would be " + (weight * 1.17));
    }

    else if (Choice == 5){
        System.out.println("Your weight on Uranus would be" +(weight * 1.05));
    }
    else if (Choice == 6) {
        System.out.println("Your weight on Neptune would be " + (weight * 1.23));
    }
    else
        System.out.println("This was not a choice, try again!");
        Choice = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Review `do-while` loop statement.

Comment: Also, you want to check about `switch` statement.

Comment: also **Choice** with *Capital Letter* stands for a class. It should be **choice** (lower case). Look for [Naming Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29)

Comment: I never had one, I'm learning on my own right now.

Comment: +1 for self-learning @Scinerio

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc, that is a nonconstructive comment.

Comment: Too bad... My answer is the one that gives the best approach, but gets downvoted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easier way to go, using a `do-while` loop and a `switch`.

Also fixed choice

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
double weight;
int choice;

System.out.println("What is your weight in pounds?");
weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

do {
    System.out.println("Which planet would you like to see your weight on?\n 1. Venus   2. Mars 3. Jupiter\n 4. Saturn  5. Uranus   6. Neptune\n 7. Exit");
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Your weight on Venus would be " + (weight * 0.78));
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Your weight on Mars would be " + (weight * .39));
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Your weight on Jupiter would be " + (weight * 2.65));
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Your weight on Saturn would be " + (weight * 1.17));
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Your weight on Uranus would be" +(weight * 1.05));
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Your weight on Neptune would be " + (weight * 1.23));
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Bye");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("This was not a choice, try again!");
            break;
    }
} while (choice != 7);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I just followed it the way I did because I'm going along with exercises on a website. This just goes to show how many different ways you can solve problems, though! Appreciate it.The question I had wasn't really part of the assignment, I just went the extra mile because knowledge is power :D

Comment: If I choose any option other than 7, (say 8) it will run as per `while` condition.

Comment: @ShijuKBabu of course it will it is done on the `default` value as: if not any of the other options then it goes again

Comment: oh yeah... I didn't notice it should run again :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn the basic in programming language... **do..while** and **switch** statements.

Here is the sample program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double weight;
        int choice;

        System.out.println("What is your weight in pounds?");
        weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

        do {

            System.out
                    .println("Which planet would you like to see your weight on?\n 1. Venus   2. Mars 3. Jupiter\n 4. Saturn  5. Uranus   6. Neptune \n7.EXIT");
            System.out.println();
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Your weight on Venus would be "
                        + (weight * 0.78));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Your weight on Mars would be "
                        + (weight * .39));
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Your weight on Jupiter would be "
                        + (weight * 2.65));
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Your weight on Saturn would be "
                        + (weight * 1.17));
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Your weight on Uranus would be"
                        + (weight * 1.05));
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Your weight on Neptune would be "
                        + (weight * 1.23));
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Leaving...");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("This was not a choice, try again!");
                break;
            }
        } while (choice != 7);

    }
```

Use the Java Naming conventions to give names to variables. Start with lowercase letter.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with a while loop. Also consider using arrays.

```
String[] planets = {"Mars", "Jupiter", .... };
double[] factors = {0.45, 1.5, ....};

double mass = keyboard.nextDouble();
int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
while (choice < 0 || choice >= planets.length)
{
    System.out.println("Not a valid option!");
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
}

double weight = mass * factors[choice];
System.out.println("Your weight on " + planets[choice] + " would be " + weight);
```

So, basically, you ask it once politely. Afterwards, start shouting that it is wrong, until the user gave a proper input.

Comment: Does not answer his question in the slightest.

Comment: @JordanD: Yeah, I realized. I fixed it :D

Comment: I went with another answer because I haven't gotten to arrays yet, that would have thrown me off a bit. Appreciate the effort, if I had more rep I'd +1.